# Memory Leak when using MKMapView in Cell

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

i would like to use a MKMapView in a SideView. The SideView contains some Cells, and i load the MapView like this: (this is my Custom UITableViewCell Class)

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "AddressCell")

    var addressMap = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0,50,250,150))

    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 48.399193
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 9.993341
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    var churchLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    var theRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(churchLocation, theSpan)

    addressMap.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

    self.contentView.addSubview(addressMap)
```

The problem here is, that the memory from the map never gets released. How do i use a map in a UITableViewCell without getting memory problems?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue, and was wondering if anyone has found a solution for it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so if you are still looking for the solution to this, I found that calling removeFromSuperview() when leaving the mapView (or before any event reloading the MapKit view) released the memory. Simply adding

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    myMap.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

to the View Controller for my MapKit View was sufficient to take care of this for me. Hopefully you have already found this (or another) solution, but I thought I would post it anyhow, just in case it saves someone some time.

`myMap` is the Outlet for my MapKit View in this example.